# Basic proofs for independent events

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega, P)$ be a probability space and $A, B \subseteq \Omega$ be independent events.

Prove the following:

(P1) $A$ and $\bar{B}$ are independent

(P2) $\bar{A}$ and $B$ are independent

(P3) $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{B}$ are independent

### Definitions / Simple rules

Two events $A, B \subseteq \Omega$ are called independent iff $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$

---

A measure $P: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called a probability measure, if

- (K1) $\forall A \subseteq \Omega: P(A) \geq 0$
- (K2) $P(\Omega) = 1$
- (K3) For every series of sets $A_1, A_2, \dots$ with $i \neq j \Rightarrow A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$, the following is true: $$P(\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(A_i)$$

---

From (K2) + (K3), it follows $P(A) = 1 - P(\bar{A})$:

$$1 \overset{K2}{=} P(\Omega) = P(A \cup \bar{A}) \overset{K3}{=} P(A) + P(\bar{A})$$

---

$$A \setminus B = A \cap \bar{B}$$

### My try

#### P1

$$
\begin{align}
P(A) \cdot P(\bar{B}) &= P(A) \cdot (1 - P(B))\\
 &= P(A) - P(A) P(B)\\
&= P(A) - P(A \cap B)\\
...(?)\\
 &= P(A \setminus (A \cap B))\\
&= P(A \setminus B)\\
&= P(A \cap \bar{B}) 
\end{align}
$$

#### P2

I guess this is exactly the same as (P1), except for renaming variables.

#### P3

I don't think this was helpful at all...

$$
\begin{align}
P(\bar{A}) \cdot P(\bar{B}) &= (1 - P(A)) \cdot (1 - P(B))\\
&= 1 - P(A) - P(B) + P(A) \cdot P(B)\\
&= 1 - P(A) - P(B) + P(A \cap B)\\
&= 1 - (P(A) - P(A \cap B)) - P(B)\\
&\overset{P1}{=} 1 - P(A \cap \bar{B}) - P(B)\\
&= P(\bar{B}) - P(A \cap \bar{B})
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof for P1 is correct. Note for the step with the question mark, that the following holds:

If $A \subset B$, then $P(A \setminus B) = P(A) - P(B)$, because $A = (A\setminus B) \cup B$ is a partition of $A$ into the two disjoint subsets $B$ and $A \setminus B$.

P2 follows from renaming the variables in P1. For P3 you don't even have to do any calculations, just aplly P1 twice.